# Granting read access to the Authenticated Users group for a file

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

How do I grant read access to the Authenticated Users group for a file? I'm using s3cmd and want to do it while uploading but I'm just focusing directly on changing the acl. What should I put in for http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers? I have tried every combination of AuthenticatedUsers possible.

> ./s3cmd setacl
> --acl-grant=read:http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers
> s3://BUCKET/FILE
>
> ./s3cmd setacl
> --acl-grant=read:AuthenticatedUsers
> s3://BUCKET/FILE

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible with s3cmd. Instead I had to switch to the aws cli tools.

Here are the directions to install them:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

It's possible to set the acl to read by authenticated users during upload with the command:

```
aws s3 cp <file-to-upload> s3://<bucket>/ --acl authenticated-read
```

Plus a whole load of other combinations you can check out here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#cli-aws-s3

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me with s3cmd version 1.6.0:
`s3cmd setacl s3://<bucket>/<file-name> --acl-grant='read:http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers'` for an individual file.

`s3cmd setacl s3://<bucket>/<dir-name> --acl-grant='read:http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers' --recursive`
 for all files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is from http://s3tools.org/s3cmd:

> Upload a file into the bucket    ~$ s3cmd put addressbook.xml
>   s3://logix.cz-test/addrbook.xml    File 'addressbook.xml' stored as
>   s3://logix.cz-test/addrbook.xml (123456 bytes)   Note about ACL
>   (Access control lists) — a file uploaded to Amazon S3 bucket can
>   either be private, that is readable only by you, possessor of the
>   access and secret keys, or public, readable by anyone. Each file
>   uploaded as public is not only accessible using s3cmd but also has a
>   HTTP address, URL, that can be used just like any other URL and
>   accessed for instance by web browsers.
>
> > ~$ s3cmd put --acl-public --guess-mime-type storage.jpg
> >     s3://logix.cz-test/storage.jpg   File 'storage.jpg' stored as
> >     s3://logix.cz-test/storage.jpg (33045 bytes)   Public URL of the 
> >     object is: http://logix.cz-test.s3.amazonaws.com/storage.jpg
>
> Now anyone can display the storage.jpg file in their browser. Cool, eh?

try changing public to authenticated and that should work.

see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ACLOverview.html#CannedACL
it explains on amazon side how to use their ACLs, supposedly if you use public in s3cmd - this would translate to *public-read* in amazon, so authenticated should translate to *authenticated-read*.

Comment: That didn't work. It is not an option in the flags. It doesn't look like s3cmd supports it at all. I was hoping someone would lead me to bucket policy syntax or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Python, the boto library provides all the functionality to get and set an ACL; from the [boto S3 documentation](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html):

```
b.set_acl('public-read')
```

Where b is a bucket. Of course in your case you should change 'public-read' to 'authenticated-read'. You can do something similar for keys (files).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it at bucket level you can do -

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucketname --grant-full-control uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers
```

Docs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example command that will set the ACL on an S3 object to  `authenticated-read`.

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --acl authenticated-read --bucket mybucket --key myfile.txt
```

.