# s3cmd setacl to grant 'Authenticated Users'

Tags: jgit, s3cmd

I'm using [jgit to create a remote in s3](http://gabrito.com/post/storing-git-repositories-in-amazon-s3-for-high-availability).  When I do a `jgit push s3 master` it creates the files in s3 as owned by just my aws user (the one that did the push).

I want these files to also have 'Authenticated users' permissions.

I have tried the following:

- Setting `acl: authenticated-read` in the ~/.jgit file (this throws error as only 'public' or 'private' is supported from what I can tell.
- modify the acl after the push via `s3cmd`: `s3cmd --add-header=x-amz-acl:authenticated-read setacl --acl-private s3://my.bucket/repo/*`.  This seems to have no impact on the ACL of the files (its like nothing ran, no error though)

How do I do one of the following:

1. Configure jgit to set 'Authenticated users' acl when pushing to s3 (I'd prefer this)
2. Use s3cmd (or another existing command line tool) to set the acl of existing files to 'Authenticated users'

Comment: what do you mean by not working? it does not compile? it does not run properly? it does not have any effect? Please tell how you determined it does not work. And did you take a look around for almost similar questions?

Comment: yea that wasn't very clear was it. Long day :). I have clarified. Yes I've looked around for similar q's/googled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Granting read access to the Authenticated Users group for a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979384/granting-read-access-to-the-authenticated-users-group-for-a-file)